# Create Year from Term Code / Manipulating date strings in SAS

Tags: string, date, sas

I'm converting a term code to a year value.  So I have term codes similar to ..

```
data terms ; 
input term_code $; 
cards;
199900
199910
199920
200000
200010
200020
200100
200110
200120
201000
201010
; 
run;
```

and I can convert them to what I want with the following code...

```
data terms_Year ; set terms ; 

if(Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) >= '2010')
   then Year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-1' || ( 1  *  Substr ( Term_Code, 4,1 ) + 1 );
else if(Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) >= '2009')
   then year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-'  || ( 1  *  Substr ( Term_Code, 4,1 ) + 1 );
else if(Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) >= '2000')
   then year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-0' || ( 1  *  Substr ( Term_Code, 4,1 ) + 1 );
else if(Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) =  '1999')
   then year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-00';
else    year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-'  ||  ( 1  *  Substr ( Term_Code, 3,2 ) + 1 );
        year = compress(year,,'s');
;
run;

proc print data=terms_year ; run;
```

And this is satisfactory, but I can't help but be curious how a veteran SAS programmer would tackle such a problem.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check out [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and consider posting this question there since your code actually works.

Comment: I find it useful to post an example of what you want your output to look like as well as the code. It makes it faster to make suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some functions instead, since it seems the year is the first 4 characters you can then just add 1 to get the second year and truncate it to get only the last two characters.

```
data terms_Year ; 
    set terms ; 
    year2=input(substr(year,1, 4), 4.);
    Year_want=catx("-", put(year2, 4. -l), substr(put(year2+1, 4. -l), 3));
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a more readable alternative and simple enough.  Not quite the format / informat stuff I was thinking about.. and it's a little annoying to have to create / then drop variables..

```
data terms_Year ; set terms ; 
drop year_0 year_1 ; 

if(Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) >= '2010')
   then Year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-1' || ( 1  *  Substr ( Term_Code, 4,1 ) + 1 );
else if(Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) >= '2009')
   then year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-'  || ( 1  *  Substr ( Term_Code, 4,1 ) + 1 );
else if(Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) >= '2000')
   then year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-0' || ( 1  *  Substr ( Term_Code, 4,1 ) + 1 );
else if(Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) =  '1999')
   then year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-00';
else    year = Substr ( Term_Code, 1, 4 ) || '-'  ||  ( 1  *  Substr ( Term_Code, 3,2 ) + 1 );
        year = compress(year,,'s');

year_0 = compress(substr(term_code,1,4)); 
year_1 = compress(year_0 + 1 );
year_also = catx('-',year_0, substr(year_1,3,2));
;
run;

proc print data=terms_year ; run;
```